# How to express this"a[0:3, 0:3]" in python as c++(pybind11)?

Tags: pybind11

Recently, when using pybind11, I encountered how to use python code `a[0: 3,0: 3]` to achieve this problem. There is currently a slice function, but I did not find the relevant user manual, resulting in the incorrect access.

ps: I have tried this way you said before, but when I printed out the matrix, I found it was not right. I don’t know the reason. Please help me. Thank you very much.

[cout result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JGtX.png)

```
py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
py::module np = py::module::import("numpy");
py::object random = np.attr("random");
py::module sys = py::module::import("sys");
py::print(sys.attr("path"));

py::module scipy = py::module::import("scipy.ndimage");

// get scipy.optimize.curve_fit
py::function affine_transform = scipy.attr("affine_transform");
py::array_t<float> new_affine = np.attr("eye")(4);
py::array_t<float> new_af = new_affine[py::make_tuple(py::slice(0, 3, 1), py::slice(0, 3, 1))];

std::cout << numpy_to_cv_mat(new_affine) << endl;
std::cout << new_af.size() << endl;
std::cout << numpy_to_cv_mat(new_af) << endl;



cv::Mat numpy_to_cv_mat(py::array_t<float>& input)  {   py::buffer_info buf = input.request();  cv::Mat mat(buf.shape[0], buf.shape[1], CV_32FC1, (float*)buf.ptr);     return mat; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few details required need here. First, `py::slice(start, stop, step)` creates a slice object via pybind11, like what would be created by `slice(start, stop, step)` in Python.
 Second, given a `py::array` object `a`, the `[]` operator does work for slicing in C++ (`a[py::slice(s0,s1,st)]`) *but* there is a big caveat: `a[]` allows (and compiles) with multiple arguments, but only one argument is actually used for slicing, so `a[slice(...), slice(...)]` only applies the slice on the first dimension.

For multi-dimensional slicing, the `[]` operator must be passed a `py::tuple` of `py::slice` objects. For example, `a[0:3,0:3]` in Python would be translated to the following in C++:

```
// a is py::array
a[py::make_tuple(py::slice(0,3,1), py::slice(0,3,1))]
```

Putting this together, here's a full example which creates and slices a 2D array based on start/stop inputs:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

py::array do_slice(py::array a, py::int_ start, py::int_ stop) {
  auto res = a[py::make_tuple(py::slice(start, stop, 1), py::slice(start, stop, 1))];
  return res;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(ex, m) {
  m.def("do_slice", &do_slice);
}
```

Some usage examples after compiling:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> import ex
>>> ex.do_slice(a, 0, 1)
array([[0]])
>>> ex.do_slice(a, 0, 2)
array([[0, 1],
       [4, 5]])
>>> ex.do_slice(a, 0, 3)
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would also like to ask you how to convert "py :: array_t" to "cv :: Mat". For example, through this operation "py :: array_t <float> new_af = new_affine [py :: make_tuple (py :: slice (0, 3, 1), py :: slice (0, 3, 1))]; "How to export new_af to" cv :: Mat ", thank you

Comment: I would suggest to ask new question.